# change cells with range.replace

Tags: c#, excel

well I have a mini program changing all excel cells beginning with ='C:\, but I have a problem. I use range.replace for do this, but my program work wrong, because it don't change all the cells contain ='C:\, only change the first find it and I don't know for what reason.

My code is :

```
foreach (Excel.Worksheet sheet in xlWorkBook.Sheets)
{
    string sheetName = sheet.Name;
    Console.WriteLine(sheetName);


    //seleccion rango activo
    range = sheet.UsedRange;

    //leer las celdas
    int rows = range.Rows.Count;
    int cols = range.Columns.Count;
    //Excel.Range startCell = sheet.Cells[1, 1];
    //Excel.Range endCell = sheet.Cells[rows, cols];
    sheet.Range["A1:J1000"].Replace(@"='C:\", @"='T:\");

    //range = sheet.UsedRange;
    // leer las celdas
    //int rows = range.Rows.Count;
    //int cols = range.Columns.Count;

    //}
    // liberar
    releaseObject(sheet);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do another `foreach`-Loop for every cell in the selected range.

I have no way of testing this right now, but this should work:

```
object whatToReplace = "what you want to replace";
object replacement = "what you want to replace it with";

foreach(Range cell in range)
{
    cell.Replace(whatToReplace, replacement);
}
```

Comment: No, that is not the problem you can do this and it works, replacing all the "A" by "B" in A1:A10 range. Range("A1:A10").Replace what:="A", Replacement:="B"

Comment: What is the solution ?